How does calculation of Gauss quadrature rule from Jacobi matrix follow in Golub/Welsch's classic paper?
I am trying to understand how Golub and Welsch arrive at their classic formula for the weights in Gaussian quadrature, eq. (2.6) in Golub and Welsch, Calculation of Gauss Quadrature Rules, 1969. I do not see how the inline equation $q_{1,j}^2=w_j(p_0(t_j))^2$ immediately after eq. (2.5) follows from (2.3) and (2.5), as claimed. Can someone explain this?

Moderators, please leave up @Ahmad Barhoumi's answer as it is correct!

It looks to me like the authors take $p_j(x)$ to be the orthonormal polynomials, which means $T$ will be automatically symmetric (i.e. $T = J$ and $D = \mathbb{I}$). If so, then $\mathbf{q}_j$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $t_j$ normalized to have length 1. But $\mathbf{p}(t_j)$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $t_j$. I suspect this paper is about positive weights ($w(x) \geq 0$ on $[a, b]$) and so the zeros of the corresponding orthogonal polynomials are simple, or $t_j \neq t_k$ if $j \neq k$. So, each eigenspace is 1-dimensional and $\mathbf{q}_j$ is a multiple of $\mathbf{p}(t_j)$; equation (2.3) just says that to normalize $\mathbf{p}(t_j)$ you need to multiply by $\sqrt{w_j}$, in which case $\mathbf{q}_j = \sqrt{w_j}\mathbf{p}(t_j)$. Comparing the first entries gives you $q_{1, j} = \sqrt{w_j} p_0(t_j)$ and now you can square both sides to get the equality you asked about.
